# how do I add a picture inside of a cookie JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I am making a website, and I'd like to store a picture in a cookie in my account page. When I upload a profile picture, it works fine, but when I reload, the profile picture is the default picture instead of the picture I picked earlier. How do I make it so when I refresh the page the profile picture stays the same instead of being the default picture? My code:

```js
function preview_image(event) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(){
        var output = document.getElementById('output_image');
        output.src = reader.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="guest.png" id="output_image">
        <input type="file"accept="image/*"onchange="preview_image(event)" id="file">
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** you can now use php.

Comment: Can you delete code that isn't relevant to the problem, like that small mountain of CSS?

Comment: What does "cookie in a picture" mean?

Comment: sorry it was a typo. I'll fix that

Comment: The maximum size of a cookie is 4096 bytes, and the only possible way to store an image into a cookie would be base64 encoded, which will increase the size of the image by roughly 33%, so 133% of original size in bytes roughly. so your maximum image size would be 66% of 4096 bytes, unless you split the image across multiple cookies. So could it be done? sure. should it? obviously not, and regardless you have shown zero effort as your code doesn't do anything to attempt to store the image in a cookie at all.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user hasn't shown any effort to do what he is requesting.

Comment: @DrakeKrewson you should not attempt to store an image in a cookie. you can store much more data in local storage, much more easily and with infinite persistence. you will still need to base64 encode the image data. you can google the technique of converting binary to base64 and reversing base64 to binary. then you can google how to store/retrieve/delete in localstorage. its very easy.

Comment: your code will be:
storing: load image data with file reader -> convert binary to base64 -> store base64
loading: load base64 from localStorage -> convert to binary -> set binary as image source (or you can also just set content type and do base64 as image source. just google it. there are lots of ways to skin this cat and all of them are better than trying to store an image in a cookie.

Comment: @r3wt, I'm new to JavaScript. I'm trying my best, but don't have any knowledge of cookies.

Comment: I would say that the whole way of thinking is wrong in the beginning. If the user uploads an image, that person should do that to a server. You don't upload something by storing it in the browser. So you need to set up a server that stores the image, and then have the server script give the image path to the user. I'm therefor voting to close this question.

Comment: @RickardElimää what you say is true, however Drake is a beginner. It seems this is some type of beginners exercise, perhaps for a course or assignment. And as Endless' answer highlights, it gives a good chance for him to learn about the various tools at his disposal for things like this.

Answer (score 4):

- Cookie are not a good place to store a image due to size limitation (it will also send that cookie on every other page to the server and wasting data)
- LocalStorage is no good either as it requires to convert the binary into base64 and waste space and time converting to/from base64. LocalStorage is just a simple key/value storage (as strings) and isn't meant to store large data or binary. Everything in localStorage has to be loaded into the memory on every page load so it slows down performances. Only keep small things like `theme: "dark-mode"`
- IndexedDB is a viable option, but all that code that's needed for storing a simple blob (File) isn't worth the complexity of setting up a database/table and working with callbacks
- Blinks old sandboxed file system is also grate but it's outdated and not implemented in all browsers
- The newer (spec'ed) sandboxed file system access is better! but it's too new and experimental at this point and also only implemented by Blink behind a flag

There is a other place to store raw binary data doe: in [cache storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache)!

```html
<input type=file id=$fileInput>
<img id="$imgElm">
```

```js
// load image from cache on page load
caches.open('fs').then(cache => {
  cache.match('/preview_image')
    .then(res => res.blob())
    .then(blob => $imgElm.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob))
    .catch(() => { /* no img stored */})
})

$fileInput.onchange = async evt => {
  // preview the new image
  $imgElm.src = URL.createObjectURL($fileInput.files[0])
  // cache it
  const cache = await caches.open('fs')
  await cache.delete('/preview_image') // perhaps not needed
  await cache.put('/preview_image', new Response($fileInput.files[0]))
}
```

Didn't use SO editors since it have disabled storage in sandboxed iframes... here is a fiddle instead: https://jsfiddle.net/2tnwku63/

(select a image, reload the page - and it's still there)

---

cache was not intended to store files, only request <-> response with service worker in mind, but if you convert files into a response and abuse it a bit in some ways then it can serve as a flat, low level, sandboxed, file system - doe you need to keep track what you store more manually. There is no concept of subfolders in the cache storage... on the + side you can write large data as a ReadableStream

---

If you want to be more creative then you could always store a hole [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) by doing

```js
const formData = new FormData()
formData.set('image_upload', file)

cache.put(req, new Response(formData))`
```

Then you can use `response.formData().then(fd => fd.get('image_upload'))` to get an actual file back with the FileName included as a File instances (instead of a blob), you could always store the the hole form by just doing `new Response(new FormData(formElm))` and you will then have saved all input fields if you have to go back a page and refill every form input

Comment: It's a power feature and require a secure origin (aka https, or localhost)

Comment: Oh, and you can forget about IE - no support there (it's dead now anyway)

Comment: UPDATE: I configured localhost, still didn't work

Comment: what kind of error do you get? look in the console, and what browser are you using?

Comment: there was no error, the problem was it didn't save the profile (i.e it still displays the default image). no errors were found and my browser was google chrome.

Answer (score 3):

You need a storage to do that. Because you are not "saving" the image anywhere, just using it one time. If its just a "test" you can save this image  as a Blob using localStorage. And then you should get it from localStorage when page loads.

Check this: [Mozilla Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: fweydson is correct, you can do this very easily in local storage. see my comment above.